# How to do @hapi/joi validation for the following?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

In the following schema i need like , if type is withdraw => [name,accountNumber,ifscCode,branchName,comments,upiId,amount,bonus,userId] to pass 
but if type is deposit i need => [txnReferenceId,amount,bonus,userId] to pass.

```
    const withdrawDepositValidatorSchema = Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string(),
        name: Joi.string(),
        accountNumber: Joi.number(),
        ifscCode: Joi.string().alphanum(),
        branchName: Joi.string(),
        comments: Joi.string(),
        upiId: Joi.string(),
        txnReferenceId: Joi.number(),
        amount: Joi.number(),
        bonus: Joi.number(),
        userId: Joi.string()
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when` condition. I am giving one example here but can be done for other fields as well.

```
const withdrawDepositValidatorSchema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string(),
  name: Joi.when(Joi.ref("type"), {
    "is": Joi.string().valid("Withdraw"),
    "then": Joi.string(),
    "otherwise": Joi.forbidden()
  }),
```

Comment: i updated the question , i forgot to add amount , bonus , userId to first set, [amount,bonus,userId] is common to both.

Comment: I have provided you the way to do it. If it is done for one field, I am sure you can workout for the other fields as well